In tongue and groove sheathing more wasteful?
I am trying to compare sheathing using regular 8' x 4' boards vs tongue and groove equivalent. Unless your project utilizes exact multiples of 4' (or 47 1/2" for a typical T@G) for sheathed surface width, you'll need to cut down your sheets to size - 2', 1' or even 1" wide.
Now with the straight edge board, I can use one board to make multiple narrow strips. With T&G board, I can utilize only the side with the tongue (or groove, depending on which way I go) and have to throw the rest away. Right? If my edge strips need to be just 1" wide, that sounds like a lot of waste.

Can always cut off the tongue, so only waste 1/4 or 3/8 inch of the sheet.  Tongue & groove is usually saved for floors, since slightly stronger seams.

For walls, the extra strength gained by tongue and groove is usually not needed, so banging a straight edge up to a groove edge will not matter that much.

No, using T&G shouldn't be significantly more wasteful compared to using straight-edge sheets. Strategy for efficient use may require some forethought though.
T&G is just a time-saving method for stiffening the edges of sheets where they span between supporting lumber. Joining the edges helps reduce deflection, bounce, and noise, and also strengthens the diaphragm. So far as I can tell it only makes sense to use T&G when they'll be oriented so that the T&G axis of the sheet is perpendicular to the supporting studs/joists/whatever. The cut-off excess portion from one row of sheets can be used to start the next row.
An edge strip of just 1" wide is so narrow that if it isn't supported on the back side it's liable to break, tongue and groove not withstanding. Don't fret over having a tongue or groove present on such a skinny strip. For strips of many inches or wider you can glue and nail blocking spanning the back side of the edge joint and gain equal (or better?) strength to what T&G offers.
Do you have a router, or need an excuse to buy one? You can make your own tongues or grooves with an appropriate bit.
Rough tongues could be formed even with just circular saw. Grooves could be formed with a table saw if the strip is not too wide to manage standing on edge against the saw fence. Tongues could be made on a table saw as well, standing up or lying down. Forming these features with a saw will take multiple passes or a dado blade.

Thank you! Is it then true that to avoid waste, I need to be prepared to carve my own tongues and groves?

@Alexander Carving your own tongues and grooves is one way, but honestly, I don't see a professional framer doing much of that. Instead they'll plan the placement such that when a full sheet is cut to fit a spot, the portion that was cut off is used to start the next row. Where that doesn't work out they'll probably use blocking in lieu of T&G -- it's likely that blocking can be placed faster than custom tongues or grooves can be crafted.
